# Groovy MetaClass change to Service Under Test is not used by Spock

Tags: grails, groovy, spock, metaclass

Within a Spock unit test, I am trying to test the behaviour of a method `findRepositoriesByUsername` independent of `getGithubUrlForPath`, both belonging to the same service.

Repeated attempts to use the `metaClass` have failed:

- `String.metaClass.blarg` produces an error `No such property: blarg for class: java.lang.String`
- `service.metaClass.getGithubUrlForPath` to modify the service instance doesn't work
- `GithubService.metaClass.getGithubUrlForPath` to modify the service class doesn't work
- Tried adding/modifying methods on the `metaClass` in the test methods' setup and when blocks, neither worked as expected

The test:

```
package grails.woot

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(GithubService)
class GithubServiceSpec extends spock.lang.Specification {

    def 'metaClass test'() {
        when:
        String.metaClass.blarg = { -> 
            'brainf***'
        }

        then:
        'some string'.blarg == 'brainf***'
    }

    def 'can find repositories for the given username'() {
        given:
        def username = 'username'
        def requestPathParts

        when: 'the service is called to retrieve JSON'
        service.metaClass.getGithubUrlForPath = { pathParts ->
            requestPathParts = pathParts
        }
        service.findRepositoriesByUsername(username)

        then: 'the correct path parts are used'
        requestPathParts == ['users', username, 'repos']
    }

}
```

The service:

```
package grails.woot

import grails.converters.JSON

class GithubService {

    def apiHost = 'https://api.github.com/'

    def findRepositoriesByUsername(username) {
        try{
            JSON.parse(getGithubUrlForPath('users', username, 'repos').text)
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // user not found
        }
    }

    def getGithubUrlForPath(String ... pathParts) {
        "${apiHost}${pathParts.join('/')}".toURL()
    }
}
```

I've tested the `String.metaClass.blarg` example in the groovy shell (launched by grails), and it did as expected.

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding here?  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to handle the desired test (replacing a method on the service under test)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the tests can be written to make them pass:

```
def 'metaClass test'() {
    given:
        String.metaClass.blarg = { -> 'brainf***' }

    expect:
        // note blarg is a method on String metaClass 
        // not a field, invoke the method
        'some string'.blarg() == 'brainf***'
}

def 'can find repositories for the given username'() {
    given:
        def username = 'username'
        def requestPathParts

    when: 'the service is called to retrieve JSON'
        service.metaClass.getGithubUrlForPath = { String... pathParts ->
            requestPathParts = pathParts
            [text: 'blah'] // mimicing URL class
        }
        service.findRepositoriesByUsername(username)

    then: 'the correct path parts are used'
        requestPathParts == ['users', username, 'repos']
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The `blarg` mistake should have been obvious from the error, but I missed that completely.  The `getGithubUrlForPath` issue appears to be the lack of type in the closure argument.  This makes sense now!  I suppose a new method was added `getGithubUrlForPath(Object pathParts)`, rather than the existing one being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Spock's great Mocking abilities?

Look at http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_creating_mock_objects

There is no need to peek  inside metaclass itself, you can create some stub object, and demanded method will be called instead of original one. Also you can use Groovy's MockFor and StubFor, they can be a little bit easier.

You cannot fully trust metaclass inside spock tests specification.

1. There is some complex logic inside it, which can easyly mess thing's up. Try run some tests under debugger, and you will see it.
2. Spock uses metaclasses under the hood. It can override your own try's.

Comment: I think I'm still missing something...  Both `findRepositoriesByUsername` and `getGithubUrlForPath` belonging to the same service (under test), with the former calling the latter.  I don't understand how I can mock the response from `getGithubUrlForPath` when it is called by `findRepositoriesByUsername`.